# how to make copy of unique_ptr wih custom deleter

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, unique-ptr

I am getting compilation errors if I  make a copy of unique_ptr with   custom deleter . Please some one help me out .

```
#include <iostream>
#include<memory>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

auto del = [](int *p) { cout <<"obj deleted "<<endl;delete p;};
int main()
{
   unique_ptr<int, decltype(del)> p1(new int(10), del);
   unique_ptr<int,decltype(del)> p2;
   p2 = std::move(p1);
}
```

Errors:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\tuple||In instantiation of 'constexpr std::_Head_base<_Idx, _Head, true>::_Head_base() [with unsigned int _Idx = 1u; _Head = <lambda(int*)>]':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\tuple|353|required from 'constexpr std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head>::_Tuple_impl() [with unsigned int _Idx = 1u; _Head = <lambda(int*)>]'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\tuple|202|required from 'constexpr std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>::_Tuple_impl() [with unsigned int _Idx = 0u; _Head = int*; _Tail = {<lambda(int*)>}]'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\tuple|602|required from 'constexpr std::tuple<_T1, _T2>::tuple() [with _T1 = int*; _T2 = <lambda(int*)>]'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\bits\unique_ptr.h|158|required from 'constexpr std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr() [with _Tp = int; _Dp = <lambda(int*)>]'|
F:\3d\C++CodeProject\Hello\main.cpp|10|required from here|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\tuple|59|error: use of deleted function '<lambda(int*)>::<lambda>()'|
F:\3d\C++CodeProject\Hello\main.cpp|6|note: a lambda closure type has a deleted default constructor|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\bits\unique_ptr.h||In instantiation of 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = <lambda(int*)>]':|
F:\3d\C++CodeProject\Hello\main.cpp|11|required from here|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\bits\unique_ptr.h|252|error: use of deleted function '<lambda(int*)>&<lambda(int*)>::operator=(const<lambda(int*)>&)'|
F:\3d\C++CodeProject\Hello\main.cpp|6|note: a lambda closure type has a deleted copy assignment operator|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 8 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: You should post the error you get

Comment: This isn't a copy. Good thing too, since you can't copy `unique_ptr`s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue you're having with the declaration of `p2` is that the type of the lambda is not [default constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultConstructible). Therefore every declaration of the pointer type needs to have an instance of the deleter passed to it.

You can fix this by replacing the deleter lambda with an explicit functor struct that is default constructible. Then, each instance of the pointer type will be able to create its own instance of the deleter object.

```
struct MyDeleter
{
    void operator()(int* p){cout << "deleted" << endl; delete p;}
};

int main()
{
    //don't need to specify an instance of the deleter since it is default_constructible.
    unique_ptr<int, MyDeleter> p1(new int(10)); 
    unique_ptr<int, MyDeleter> p2;
    p2 = std::move(p1);
}
```

EDIT: 
as @super said, the issue with the assignment line would also be that (pre-c++20) lambdas are also not [CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable). The functor method I posted above fixes both issues.

Comment: The problem is that the lambda is not CopyAssignable.

Comment: You missed the terminating `"`.

Comment: Another solution is to use `std::function`

Comment: @super you're correct! I was mainly concerned about the issue of the unique_ptr declaration, but code I posted fixes both issues.

Comment: @super There are two separate problems.

Answer (score 4):

Two issues.

1. Before C++20 [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) closure types are not DefaultConstructible; which cause the `std::unique_ptr` using it as deleter not DefaultConstructible too.

> Closure types are not DefaultConstructible. Closure types have `a deleted (until C++14)` `no (since C++14)` default constructor. (until C++20)
>
> If no captures are specified, the closure type has a defaulted default constructor. Otherwise, it has no default constructor (this includes the case when there is a capture-default, even if it does not actually capture anything). (since C++20)

2. Before C++20 [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) closure types are not CopyAssignable; which cause the `std::unique_ptr` using it as deleter not CopyAssignable too.

> The copy assignment operator is defined as deleted (and the move assignment operator is not declared). Closure types are not CopyAssignable. (until C++20)
>
> If no captures are specified, the closure type has a defaulted copy assignment operator and a defaulted move assignment operator. Otherwise, it has a deleted copy assignment operator (this includes the case when there is a capture-default, even if it does not actually capture anything). (since C++20)

That means, your code will work since C++20 because the lambda specifies no captures. Before that you can use `std::function` instead; e.g. `std::function<void(int*)> del = [](int *p) { cout <<"obj deleted "<<endl;delete p;};`

Comment: @MaxLanghof The proper expression should be ["The problem is not only copy-assignability but also default-constructability."](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hb90n78ooMwjYJap).

Comment: Yes, I realized that.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting an error message because there is no default constuctor in this case on unique_ptr so that they are always initalized

but you can do

```
auto del = [](int *p) { cout <<"obj deleted "<<endl;delete p;};
int main()
{
   unique_ptr<int, decltype(del)> p1(new int(10), del);
   unique_ptr<int,decltype(del)> p2(std::move(p1));
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. A `unique_ptr` can be default initialized as null.

Comment: Well it's semi-correct. Normal `unique_ptr`s can be default initialized, but not those with a lambda as deleter (because the lamdba can't be default-constructed). Right error, wrong reason.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors here (as evidenced by the error message): You cannot copy-assign the lambda (required in the construction of `p1`), and you cannot default-construct a lambda (required in default-initialization of `p2`).

This fixes both these errors:

```
auto del = [](int *p) { cout <<"obj deleted "<<endl;delete p;};
int main()
{
   unique_ptr<int, decltype(del)> p1(new int(10), std::move(del));
   unique_ptr<int, decltype(del)> p2 = std::move(p1);
}
```

Note however that only one instance of your lambda will ever be in existance this way. To generate multiple lambda instances for multiple unique pointers, you can return it from a function, use `std::function` or write a functor struct (see other answers).

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because lambdas are not default-constructible. When you declare `p2` you do not pass an argument to use as a deleter so the compiler complains about not being able to default construct it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50102451/4341534) answer already covers a clean way to use a custom deleter. But if you had to use different deleters for objects of the same class, you would either have to pass a deleter at the construction of every smart pointer, or use a type that is default-constructible so that a `nullptr` can have a "null" deleter object.

```
auto del = [](int *p) { cout << "obj deleted " << endl; delete p; };
int main() {
    unique_ptr<int, std::function<void(int*)>> p1(new int(10), del);
    unique_ptr<int, std::function<void(int*)>> p2;
    p2 = std::move(p1);
}
```

This way not only do you not have to assign a deleter when there is no object managed, but you can define and use other deleters which are always moved along with the object they are created with.